# How to get selected values from Jquery multiselect drop down using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery MultiSelect(UI Widget 1.13) in my page in which the drop down options are coming through JSON serialized ajax call.

```
<select id="SearchFilter2"></select>
```

On the same page, I have another multiselect dropdown(Let say DP1) which loads first.

```
<select id=SearchFilter1"></select>
```

When I use the code below to get the values of selected options from the list and store it in to an array, the array gets replaced with the values of the first dropdown(DP1) because it uses the same logic to get them.

Below is the jquery code i am using.

```
var selectedIDs = [];
$('.ui-multiselect-checkboxes li input[aria-selected="true"]').each(function (index) {
    selectedIDs.push($(this).attr('value'));
}
```

Is there any way to get the values directly using the id instead of using whole class with list?

Your suggestions will be real helpful and appreciated. Thanks.
**FYI- `$(this).attr('id')` gives "ui-multiselect-SearchFilter2-option-0"**

Comment: `selectedIDs.push($("#id_here").attr('value'));` ? Don't quite get the problem.

Comment: instead of using class, use the id's?

Comment: I suggest you show the relevant HTML and the full jQuery function you use. This is a bit too "minimal" and hardens understanding of your issue. (You have an "edit" link below your question).